# Find & Compare with visual outcome of differences..?

Tags: vba, excel

Can somebody help me create a macro to compare some rows, If it has a difference then to put something visual so I can notice it easily?

For example:
I have..
Column A: A list of numbers (say 1 to 10,000)
Column B: A list of text e.g Yes or No

Column F: Another list of numbers (say 1 to 10,000)
Column G: Another list of Yes or No

I need to compare Columns A & F .. to find the duplicates, Once it has found duplicates to then compare Columns B & G.
If B & G = Same e.g both yes or no then do nothing
If B & G = Are different e.g B is yes & G is no then hightlight that row OR put something into Column H saying ERROR or something visual to stand out so I can notice it.

However, Columns A & F are jumbled up.. They're not the same.. Each for example does have the same numbers but not in the same place.

Is this possible to do via a loop so it does every row?

[image]

Comment: You could do this with a `VLOOKUP()` in Col C.  Eg: in C1 - `=VLOOKUP(A1,F$1:G$30,2,FALSE)`

Comment: Looks to be working fine, Thanks :)

EDIT: Doesn't work, Its not comparing the values :(

Comment: This will works, However if I put that into row C.. then I need to compare row B & C

Comment: You can use conditional formatting for that, or add a second formula in ColD, or build it into the formula in ColC.

Answer (score -1):

Add a formula that compares the values.

For example in `D1` type `=B1=G1` to show either `TRUE` or `FALSE`, or even better, type `=IF(B1=G1,"","ERROR")`. Then select the range `B1:B30` and press `Ctrl+D` to copy the formula down.

EDIT:

Sorry, I missed the jumbled up part.

Type formula `=VLOOKUP(F1,$A$1:$B$17,2,FALSE)=G1` (or the formula `=IF(VLOOKUP(F1,$A$1:$B$17,2,FALSE)=G1,"","ERROR")`) in `D1`, then `Ctrl+D` to copy it down.

EDIT 2:

The formula works well. If you get `#N/A` it's because the `VLOOKUP` function doesn't find a value in the table. Below you can see the results using these formulas:

```
I1 =VLOOKUP(F1,$A$1:$B$17,2,FALSE)=G1
J1 =IF(VLOOKUP(F1,$A$1:$B$17,2,FALSE)=G1,"","Different")
K1 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F1,$A$1:$B$17,2,FALSE)=G1,"Missing")
L1 =IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(F1,$A$1:$B$17,2,FALSE)=G1,"","Different"),"Missing")
```

[image]